# Android camera autofocus speed

Tags: android, android-camera

I use camera API at my application and autofocus works very slow (and ugly).
There are some apps at store, that have have a quick response (the same as native camera app).
Is it possible to increase speed/quality using camera api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just an idea, but you may try [FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE).

As far as I know, the Focus is pretty Hardware dependend, espacially on Samsung devices, so the native app might have a little advance. But I guess `FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE` should be quicker in most cases if it is supported. The continuous focus for vidos does usually a great job, so it should also work for pictures.

Comment: In aditional: never call autoFocus, this can disable FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE

Comment: It does disable it, but you can re-enable it right away by calling cancelAutoFocus() on your camera object (as written in the link above)